# function to print a triangle of # tags in python

Tags: python

I am trying to formulate a function to print a triangle of hash tags. The triangle should be should be upside down when I input a negative, vice versa when I input a positive number.

```
def triangle(num):

    tag = '#'

    for x in range(num):
        print((x * tag) + tag)

    num = abs(num)
    for i in range(num-1, -1, -1):
        print((i * tag) + tag)


triangle(3)


positive 3 should display
#
##
###

negative 3 should display
###
##
#
```

Comment: OK. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the if statement to check if num is negative.

```
def triangle(num, tag='#'):
    if num > 0:
        for x in range(num):
            print((x * tag) + tag)
    else:
        num = abs(num)
        for i in range(num-1, -1, -1):
            print((i * tag) + tag)
```

As mentioned by Metapod change `(x*tag)+tag` to `(x+1)*tag`.

```
def triangle(num, tag='#'):
    if num > 0:
        for x in range(num):
            print((x+1) * tag)
    else:
        num = abs(num)
        for i in range(num-1, -1, -1):
            print((i+1) * tag)
```

Comment: To avoid the ```+ tag```, you can use ```(x+1)``` instead of ```x``` alone => ```print((x+1) * tag)```

Comment: yes you are right, that part was copied from the original code and I did not look at it since I was focusing on the "problem" that there should be an `if` statement. I will edit my answer to include your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for you:

```
def triangle(num):

    tag = '#'
    if num > 0:
        for x in range(num):
            print((x * tag) + tag)
    else:
        num = abs(num)
        for i in range(num-1, -1, -1):
            print((i * tag) + tag)


triangle(3)
# #
# ##
# ###

triangle(-3)
# ###
# ##
# #
```